# API Gateway request blocked by CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway put method to post an image to S3 bucket. In API Gateway settings when I add */* in Binary Media Types I get the following error message

```
Access to fetch at ‘some_invokation_request/my_s3_bucket/image.png’ from origin ‘http://localhost:3001’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

When I remove */* from Binary media types in settings I can post an image and when I check the posted image in S3 it's messed up.
I'll post the original image and S3 image
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is an open issue right now and you can find further details [here](https://github.com/duro/serverless-binary-cors)

Answer (score 0):

this is what saved me
https://github.com/duro/serverless-binary-cors

just install it, and use it as:

```
custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-binary-cors
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have two different errors present.  One is CORS related and the other is the upload of an image getting messed up.  I don't think they are necessarily related.  I've hit the same issue with the image upload showing the tiny white square but faced no CORS issue.

For me, the problem turned out to be trying to combine the use of `Convert to Binary (if needed)` and a mapping template on the `Integration Request`.  [According to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-control-service-api.html) (and my experience as well), if a mapping template is defined, APIGW doesn't run the Convert to Binary passthrough functionality.  What gets passed to the S3 bucket for saving is a base64 encoded string instead of *actual binary*, thus the messed up image.

*Excerpt from the linked documentation:*
"On the contentHandling property of the Integration resource, set CONVERT_TO_BINARY. Set WHEN_NO_MATCH as the passthroughBehavior property value **without defining a mapping template. This enables API Gateway to invoke the passthrough template.**"